# Can I prevent WCF from rolling back the transaction when a fault is thrown?

Tags: .net, wcf, distributed-transactions

Consider the following WCF service which participates in a distributed transaction.  The normal behavior of WCF is to roll back the transaction if any fault occurs.  Is there any way to override that behavior?

Service contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestService {
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(TestServiceFault))]
    void ThrowError();
    [OperationContract]
    void DoSomething();
    [OperationContract]
    void DoSomethingElse();
}

[DataContract]
public class TestServiceFault{}
```

Service implementation:

```
class TestService : ITestService {
    [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
    [TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Mandatory)]
    public void ThrowError() {
        throw new FaultException<TestServiceFault>(new TestServiceFault());
    }
    [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
    [TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Mandatory)]
    public void DoSomething() {
        //
        // ...
        //
    }
    [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
    [TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Mandatory)]
    public void DoSomethingElse() {
        //
        // ...
        //
    }
}
```

Client implementation snippet:

```
using(new TransactionScope()) {
    testServiceClient.DoSomething();

    try {
        testServiceClient.ThrowError();
    } catch(FaultException<TestServiceFault>) {}

    testServiceClient.DoSomethingElse();
}
```

When the FaultException is thrown from **ThrowError()**, WCF rolls back the distributed transaction which includes the work done by **DoSomething()**.  Then, the client call to **DoSomethingElse()** fails with the message *The flowed transaction could not be unmarshaled. The following exception occurred: The transaction has already been implicitly or explicitly committed or aborted.*

In my particular scenario this behavior is undesirable.  I'd like to catch the exception on the client side and continue about my business.  If any exceptions occur that I don't catch, the client will be roll back the transaction.

Note: This question is a duplicate of [How to handle a FaultException in WCF without aborting the whole transaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993592), but the accepted answer there isn't satisfactory to me - it's important that all of the operations happen within the same transaction scope.

Comment: If you have just a single transaction scope, then a failure will cause the entire transaction to rollback - that's the whole point of it, after all. If you want to have an "isolated" sub-transaction that can fail without affecting the overall transaction, you need to use the approach shown in that other question. I don't see any other approach - pick either one of those two solutions - there's no other "magic" way ...

Comment: Yeah I understand the point of this behavior, but I'd like to be able to say that faults defined in the contract (or maybe some subset) are not failures.  It looks like this is not possible though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, you could try setting the TransactionAutoComplete=false on the service side,
and then use SetTransactionComplete() to prevent the exception from rolling your work back.

Comment: That works, thanks!  I would like to find an extension point where I can do this so I can apply it as a behavior to my operations.

Comment: glad to hear, to apply this as a behavior maybe you can use some aspect oriented framwork, to apply the tran complete on exception types you specify. (probably in the post-action step)